# How to test browser url route for Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

I am working on testing how my navigator 2.0 setup handles url changes in the browser in flutter web.

The closest i have come to being able to test how my app handles url changes is to manually update state in the RouterDelegate by calling the setNewRoutePath with a config from the RouteInformationParser.

I would really like to test the navigator closer to the origin of the url change.

Any ideas and pointers would be appreciated.

My current code looks like this:

```
  //Pass routeInformation to RouterInformationParser
  RouteInformation selectShopRoute = RouteInformation(location: '/selectshop?token=321');
  RouterConfig selectShopConfig = await app.myRouteParser.parseRouteInformation(selectShopRoute);
  await app.myRouterDelegate.setNewRoutePath(selectShopConfig);

  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  //Verify that navigator state is select shop
  expect(app.myRouterDelegate.currentScreen, RouterEnum.selectshop);
  //Verify that navigator token is set correctly
  expect(app.myRouterDelegate.token, '321');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and could not find a good approach. I came up with a way to test our code and wanted to share it to you.

Basically, we have a custom RouteInformationParser, in which a location is added only for the testing purpose.

```
class MyRouteInformationParser
    extends RouteInformationParser<PageConfiguration> {

  String? customPath; // only use for testing

  @override
  Future<PageConfiguration> parseRouteInformation(
    RouteInformation routeInformation,
  ) async {
    final location = customPath ?? routeInformation.location;

    // Compute the configuration based on the location
    return PageConfiguration()
   }
}
```

In the widget test, we just create the route information parser and use it with the `MaterialApp`. Changing the `customPath` during testing has similar effect as changing the URL of the web browser.

```
final informationParser = MyRouteInformationParser();
informationParser.customPath = "my/expected/path";
```